# java web application - model design for displaying list with a sql join

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am authoring a javabean and would like to know if it should include properties to set values obtained from a sql join?
Say I have database tables for `Products and Orders.`  These are also my java bean names.

Now I want to display a list of all products but in addition to all the product properties, I want to have columns to display `last purchase date` and `last purchased by`

My db query to get the product list would need to do joins to gather the additional info.  It does not seem correct to have setters and getters for `last purchase date and last purchased by' in Product.java model.  I may want to have a 3rd column so constantly adding new columns to my bean doesn't make sense.

How do you go about this?  I seem to encounter this when needing to display lists of models in my view.

Comment: Perhaps add your entity beans in the question to make this a little clearer.

Comment: I am not using entity beans.  They are more like DTO's

Answer (score 0):

Have a Map in Product. Upon firing the sql, store hte results of the join as key value pair in the Map. K=lastpurchasedby(columnName) and V= the value
So no need to add individual attributes. They all come in key-value pairs.